# React invariant violation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap modal, which is not shown by default. Therefore, I added a jQuery script which should show the modal.

My code is the following:

```
<div>
   <div id='tableContainer'>
       <table className="table table-condensed"></table>
   </div>

   {this.state.displayDeleteModal
                    ?
                    <div>
                        <div id="myModal" className="modal fade modalMaxSize" role="dialog">
                            <div className="modal-dialog">

                            <div className="modal-content">
                              <div className="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                              </div>
                              <div className="modal-body">
                                <p>Are you sure you want to delete selected elements?</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <script>
                            {$(function(){
                                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                            })}
                        </script>
                    </div>
                    :
                    null
                }

</div>
```

Where `this.state.deleteDisplayModal` is set like this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {displayDeleteModal: false};
},
```

However, after I added the jQuery script, I started getting the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: traverseAllChildren(...): Encountered an invalid child; DOM elements are not valid children of React components.

What is causing this?

Also, is the way in which I use jQuery correct?

Comment: May be your `button` tag is used incorrectly, its can be opened, use `value` attrbiute

Comment: The error is a React error (not jquery). Could you share React (javascript) code as well?

Comment: I took the modal code from here http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: it doesnt matter where the modal code came from, the error is from the React library, not jquery or bootstrap